# In swift for iOs,I have an if / else block of code, reacting to changes in a UISwitch. How to set the uiswitch back to off in some situations?

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, cocoa-touch

In my swift iOS application, I have a simple UISwitch control. I have connected the value changed outlet to my @IBAction. The code looks like this:

```
@IBAction func userDidSelectVisibiltySwitch(_ sender: Any) {

    if self.visibilitySwitch.isOn {
       if badCondition {
           self.visibilitySwith.setOn(false, animated: false)

          return
       }
     } else { // Strangely, it executes the else (I think because the compiler is evaluating the isOn condition again when it arrives to the else {}
        // work to be done if the user has turned off the switch
     }
}
```

I suspect that in this case, as I am turning the switch off before the else is evaluated, the compiler executes the else {} statement because it evaluates the above isOn expression again. But how is that possible, given that I placed a 'return' instruction ? that is really beyond me. A confirmation of my suspect comes from the fact that if I dispatch_async using GCD the 'self.visibilitySwith.setOn(false, animated: false)' statement, it works properly without executing the else {} statement, because the evaluation of the else takes place before the control is turned off by my statement. My code now looks like this, and it works:

```
@IBAction func userDidSelectVisibiltySwitch(_ sender: Any) {

    if self.visibilitySwitch.isOn {
       if badCondition {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.visibilitySwith.setOn(false, animated: false)
            }
            return
       }
     } else { // In this case it is normal, it does not execute the else {}
        // work to be done if the user has turned off the switch
     }
}
```

I think that I am missing something important of swift in this case. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have already provided a solution, but I want to understand the problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: Calling the `setOn(_:animated:)` function should not trigger the IBAction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than accessing the `UISwitch` via your `sender` argument, you go directly to what I assume is the `IBOutlet` value. Instead of that approach, you can access the sender as outlined below:

```
@IBAction func userDidSelectVisibiltySwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.isOn && badCondition {
        sender.setOn(false, animated: false)
    } else { // In this case it is normal, it does not execute the else {}
        // work to be done if the user has turned off the switch
    }
}
```

The reason your fix is working is likely because of a slight delay introduced by the dispatch call which allows for the `IBOutlet` value to update its value.

I have also gone ahead and combined your `if` statement, as the sample you provide does not require a nested check.

**UPDATED BASED ON RMADDY'S COMMENT**

This being the solution struck me a bit of code smell, and upon further investigation, I was able to reproduce the scenarios described by OP. This was accomplished by setting the action in Storyboard as seen here:

[image]

With that setting, I saw the following:

- Original code posted by OP would fail
- Adding the DispatchQueue as demonstrated by OP would correct the switch after a brief delay
- My posted solution would correctly work

Assuming that this is what the OP has done, then the first correction would be to change the event to `Value Changed`. Then, as stated by rmaddy in the comment, this would succeed regardless of whether you use the argument or the `IBOutlet`. Based on the original question, my interpretation was that there was an issue of the outlet value and the switch's state in the interface being out of sync.

Comment: This change should have no effect on the OP's original code. Whether the switch is accessed via `sender` or the outlet makes no difference. It's a pointer to the same object.

Comment: @rmaddy I completely agree, and after your comment, I investigated further to see if I could get into the exact scenario described by OP. I was able to do so by setting the action to primary action trigger on the switch. Doing that, I saw it fail without the OP's dispatch, succeed with the dispatch, and succeed with my post. Based on that, I will update answer with this information.